# ESXi Static IP setup with gateway on different subnet

Tags: ip, vmware-esxi, static-routes

I've got an ESXi server that I'm trying to assign a static IP to. I'm having trouble setting the gateway because (I presume) the gateway is on a different subnet.

I've been able to accomplish this task on normal Linux servers by doing the following:

```
route add 172.50.99.254 eth0
route add -net default gw 172.50.99.254 eth0
```

Now using the GUI config tools for ESXi I've tried setting the following

```
IP: 172.50.5.151
Netmask: 255.255.252.0
Gateway: 172.50.99.254
```

The gateway does not stick, and when I try to add the gateway manually using esxcfg-route it says it has no route to the gateway IP. How can I get this static IP set correctly? (I don't have any control over the network setup).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use a gateway that's within your subnet, the one you're trying to us isn't.

Basically using the /22 NM your subnet range is 172.50.4.1 to 172.50.7.254 (not including 0's and 255's - which is *contentious* in these parts).

If you really wanted to get to that gateway you'd need a /17 NM (255.255.128.0) - so long as it's routable of course.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. I'm not very well versed in this networking stuff. I was basically given some static IPs to use and the rest of the settings I copied off of my desktop that's using DHCP.

Comment: Don't worry about it - nobody was born knowing this stuff, eventually you learn to do it all in your head but there are lots of web-based subnet calculators - my favourite one is this; http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/SubnetCalculator.jsp